# Replace window in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, replace, window

I want to replace the values in consecutive rows in a dataframe that are equal to a given list, e.g. `[0, 1, 0]` has to be replaced with zeroes.
So for example, if this would be applied to column A, column B would be the desired result:

```
   A  B
0  2  2
1  1  1
2  0  0
3  1  0
4  0  0
5  4  4
```

Here the rows 2, 3 and 4 match the template and hence their values are changed to 0's.

In practice, I want to do this with the column being measurements over time. And I want to replace all sections with 3 or less consecutive measurements with zeroes (because they are 'too short'). So, these measurements are 1, 2 or 3 rows padded with one row on both side with the value 0.

I have already tried a lot, for example `df['A'].replace([0, 1, 0], 0)`, but this apparently replaces any 0 or 1 with 0. And that is now what I want; only parts matching the [0, 1, 0] template should be replaced with 0's.

I hope somebody can help me out and that I have explained my problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is converting the column to string and then capture and replace '010' by '000' as follows:

```
string_a = df['A'].astype(str).str.cat().replace('010', '000')
```

Then convert it back to a list and asign it as column B:

```
df['B'] = list(string_a)
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do it. I am quite new with python

Regards,

Jorge

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed it myself by using .shift(). If you shift it both back and forth, and then the 1 overlaps with a 0 in both of the shifted versions, you can replace that 1 with a 0 to achieve the same result. This is not an good solution because it is not generally applicable, but it worked in my case.